# My code does not work. How can I delete a element in Firebase list?

Tags: javascript, json, list, firebase

I need to do something like that. Who can I help me?

```
var listRef = new Firebase("https://t3zlg47s3v6.firebaseio-demo.com/some-list");

    for (var i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++){ 
        listRef.push().set({login: "tulio"+i, email: i+"_tulio@hotmail.com", password: "teste"+i});     
    }

    listRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.val().login == 'tulio1'){
            listRef.remove(snapshot);   
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 8):

Remove does not take arguments. You instead should get a reference to the data from the snapshot and call remove, like this:

```
snapshot.ref().remove();
```

Comment: It appears that `ref` is no longer a function. `snapshot.ref.remove()` should now be correct. (at least when using `ref.once('value'...`.